# rewrite url redirect with Azure Application Gateway

Tags: azure, redirect, azure-application-gateway

I would like to use the application gateway as a reverse proxy.

All authentication request from the frontend should be routed to /auth. The application gateway should then replace query parameters of the request and should URL redirect to the resulting page. I couldn't get that working on Azure.

**Example:**

Application gateway is reachable under **test.com**

Request to: *test.com/auth*

Application gateway modifies request to *test.b2clogin.com/?scope=XY&client_id=235*

Application gateway url redirects request to *test.b2clogin.com/?scope=XY&client_id=235*

Is this possible? I couldn't figure out how to configure that

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after hours of searching I finally figured out how to do it:

1. created a */auth* endpoint. This one is routing to the *test.b2clogin.com* backend. (actually that backend is never hit via that rule)
2. created a rewrite rule for */auth*: that rule modifies url and query, set URL to */authredirect* and on query I set/modify the query parameters that I require. Enable "Re-evaluate path map" on this one, so that it directly redirects to */authredirect*.
3. configure the */authredirect* endpoint as URL Redirect to *test.b2clogin.com/.../authorize*. Also enable "Include query string"

This way Im able to modify the incoming request under */auth* and after modification I redirect it to */authredirect*.

Hope that it helps someone :)